# Handling of Dependecies on a CMake Project with multiple subprojects

Tags: c++, cmake

I have the following Structure of my Project:

```
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── libA
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   ├── include
    │   │   └── libA
    │   │       └── my_liba.h
    │   ├── src
    │   │   └── my_liba.cpp
    │   └── test
    ├── libB
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   ├── include
    │   │   └── libB
    │   │       └── my_libb.h
    │   ├── src
    │   │   └── my_libb.cpp
    │   └── test
    └── runner
        ├── CMakeLists.txt
        └── src
            └── main.cpp
```

I would like to achieve the following:

- Be able to build `libA` and `libB` and `Runner` seperately
- Be able to build all together.

For the dependency: `libB` depends on `libA` and `Runner` needs `libB`.
How do i have to configure libB and Runner?

These are the current `CMakeLists.txt` Files:

`libA/CMakeLists.txt:`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project (MyLibA)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} src/my_liba.cpp)
add_library(Example::LibA ALIAS ${PROJECT_NAME})

target_include_directories( ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
)
```

`libB/CMakeLists.txt:`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project (MyLibB)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} src/my_libb.cpp)
add_library(Example::LibB ALIAS ${PROJECT_NAME})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Example::LibA)

target_include_directories( ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
)
```

`Runner/CMakeLists.txt`

```
project(runner)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    Example::LibB
)
```

`CMakeLists.txt:`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(Example)

add_subdirectory(libA)
add_subdirectory(libB)
add_subdirectory(runner)
```

With the current configuration i can build everything out of the `lib` directory.
I could also build `libA` from inside the `libA` Directory. But i could not build `libB` or `runner` from there folders, which was to be expected, since they do not know where to find the dependencies.

How do i have to change my `CMakeFiles` to get this to work?

Comment: Why do you want to run `make` from subdirectories? Just run `make <appropriate_target>` from the root of the build dir.

Comment: I want to be able to build the `libA` and `libB` also as standalone libraries.

Comment: When you are building libB from its folder, how exactly do you want it to find libA? Would libA be already installed on the system, or do you want libB to also build libA?

Comment: @yemre thats the point where i do not know what is the best solution or if there is a best practice in cmake

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to build `libB` using only the `libB` build script you need a way of making `libB` able to find the `libA` dependency.

From your question I assume that you actually want to build `libA` as part of the `libB` building process (you don't want to install `libA` before starting the `libB` build.

This looks weird, but you could do this in `libB/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_subdirectory(../libA)
```

The problem is that doing this will break the root build script. This can be fixed by checking if the `libA` target already exists:

```
if (NOT TARGET libA)
    add_subdirectory(../libA)
endif (NOT TARGET libA)
```

In this way, you either have a `libA` target because the root build script added the `libA` subdirectory, or you add it yourself.

`add_subdirectory(../libA)` looks weird to me, and probably some people with more CMake experience will consider it bad style, but I don't see another option here, given your setup. Other things may break if you do this, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980784/cmake-add-sub-directory-which-is-not-sub-directory-on-real-directory).

As a side note, you may want to add some dependencies between your targets:

```
add_dependencies(libB libA)
```

In this way, when you build `libB`, if `libA` is not built, a `libA` build will be triggered before the `libB` build starts.

Comment: would it be also a alternative to define a variable with the directory of the libA? So that it is possible to set the variable during the build?

Comment: Yes. For example passing `-DPATH_TO_LIBA=some/path.here` will set the variable `PATH_TO_LIBA` to `some/path/here`. You can check if it was set with `if`: `if (PATH_TO_LIBA)`.

Comment: It then works like the answer from @fabian i guess

Comment: Yes. My answer assumes that you need the root build script as is, but his simplifies things.

Answer (score 0):

`add_subdirectory` allows you to pass any directory. If you don't pass a subdirectory though, you need to pass a second parameter specifying the binary directory use for this "subtree" of the sources. of course you need to make sure not to create circles.

This allows you to add the source directories of the projects a target depends on resulting in the following inclusions of source dirs:

- `libB/CMakeLists.txt` includes `libA`
- `runner/CMakeLists.txt` includes `libB`
- `CMakeLists.txt` either includes ***only*** `runner` or is removed entirely (you could simply use `runner` as source dir instead)

A convenient location to use for the binary dirs would be subdirectories of the binary dir.

#### Changes to your `CMakeLists.txt` files

**`libA/CMakeLists.txt`**

remains unmodifies

**`libB/CMakeLists.txt`**

Create a directory to use as source dir and add the `add_subdirectory`

```
set(LIB_A_BINARY_DIR "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/subproject_build_dirs/libA")
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${LIB_A_BINARY_DIR})
add_subdirectory("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../libA" ${LIB_A_BINARY_DIR})
```

**`runner/CMakeLists.txt`**

Similar to the changes above, but also add `cmake_minimum_required` to avoid cmake from producing warnings, if you want to use `runner` as the source dir.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

set(LIB_B_BINARY_DIR "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/subproject_build_dirs/libB")
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${LIB_B_BINARY_DIR})
add_subdirectory("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../libB" ${LIB_B_BINARY_DIR})
```

**`CMakeLists.txt`**

If you want to keep this file instead of using `runner/CMakeLists.txt` directly it should be changed to the following

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(Example)

add_subdirectory(runner)
```